# Pythom3 regex query

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am a new comer to python and started my own python task to identify the program names from a report generated by z/OS (sent to me as a txt file). The sample data looks like this,

```
<*** MEMBER AA2500 ***> 
<*** MEMBER AA2600 ***> 
<*** MEMBER AA3A60 ***> 
<*** MEMBER AA3A50 ***>
```

I have tried the RegEx pattern ,

```
pgmName = re.findall(r'[<][*]*\s[A-Z]*\s[A-Z]*\d[0-9](?:[A-Z]|[0-9])\d[0-9]*\s[*]*[>]', inputString)
```

to idenify this and eventually writen to another text file.
But the problem is 3rd and 4th members are not getting identified using this pattern.

Could someone please guide me to fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: query updated...

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to guess what you need, if I don't see other strings from your file. However, the following pattern works for your case:

```
MATCH = re.compile(r'''
^\<\** # opening tag
\s[A-Z]* # MEMBER
\s[A-Z,0-9]* # ID
\s\**\>$ # closing tag
''', re.X)

pgmName = MATCH.findall(inputString)
```

You could be even more concrete in specifying the number of some characters

```
MATCH = re.compile(r'''
^\<\*{3} # opening tag
\sMEMBER # MEMBER
\s[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z,0-9]\d{2} # ID
\s\*{3}\>$ # closing tag
''', re.X)
```

But it largely depends on the data...